# Trapezoid rule over trigonometric polynomials

Tags: trigonometry, integration, numerical-methods, fourier-series

The question is regarding trapezoid rule applied on trigonometric polynomials

Here is the question

> Show that the composite trapezoid rule over an equidistant partitioning with interval size  $h = 2 * \pi / (n+1)$ is exact for all trigonometric polynomials of period $ 2 \pi$, i.e., for functions of the form $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=-n}^n c_{k}e^{ikt}$.,
>   where i is the imaginary unit.`

Now, I have no idea what he means by that question. What do they mean by exact?

Thank you for your time.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint, what if we wrote a formula for trigonometric polynomials as:

$$\displaystyle f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} a_k \cos kx + b_k \sin kx$$

Then:

$$\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) dx = \frac{2 \pi}{n} \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} f(\frac{2 \pi i}{n})$$

Now, try an example and see if you can show this.

Comment: $\large +1^{\ddot\smile}$

Answer (score 0):

The composite trapezoid rule applied to the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with $n+1$ intervals $(n+2)$ points including the ends is that $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) dx \approx \frac 1{2(n+1)}\left(f(0)+2f(\frac {2\pi}{n+1}) + 2f(\frac {2*2\pi}{n+1}+\ldots+2f(\frac {n*2\pi}{n+1})+f(2\pi)\right)$

You are to evaluate the integral and the approximation for your functions and show they are equal.