# Showing that the composite trapezoid rule is invariant to certain symmetry

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, symmetry

I am trying to show that if $f$ holds certain symmetric properties
than the composite trapezoid rule 
$$
T(n) = (b-a)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2n} + \frac{b-a}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(x_k)
$$
is invariant over the function. Here $x_k = a + (b-a)k/n$.

**Proposition**
Given that $f$ is a continuous function on an interval $x\in[a,b]$
with
$$f(x) + f(a+b-x)$$
Then we have

1. $T(1) = (b-a)[f(a)+f(b)]/2$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} T(k) = T(1)$
3. $T(k) = T(1) \ \forall \, k \in \mathbb{N}$

The first point is easy to show, and I think I was able to use a cheecky handwaving argument for the second
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}   T(n) & =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f\left(x_k\right) \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} f\left(x_k\right)+f(x_{n-k})\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2} f(a) + f(b) \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\left( \frac{n-1}{2}\right)(f(a) + f(b))\\
& = (b-a)\left[\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}\right]
\end{align*}
Alas this only works if $n$ is even, otherwise you are left with a single term in the middle.. The same problem goes for 3, harder to prove when $n$ is odd. 
I also had some minor problems justifying why $f(x_k) +f(x_{n-k})$ is constant.
Intuitively it makes sense but yeah, any help dealing with the middle term or proving this would be great.

Intuitively what it means that $f(x)+f(a+b-x)$ is constant is somewhat explained 
[here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/CMJ/Nelsen39-41.pdf). The question is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376652/trapezoid-rule-over-trigonometric-polynomials), but the class of functions satisfying $f(x)+f(a+b-c)$ is larger than the set of $C_{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have writing $C := f(a) + f(b)$
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(x_k) &= \frac 12\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(x_k)  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(x_{n-k})\right)\\
    &= \frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \bigl(f(x_k) + f(x_{n-k})\bigr)\\
    &= \frac{n-1}2 \cdot C
\end{align*}
Hence 
\begin{align*} T(n) &= \frac{b-a}{2n}\cdot C + \frac{b-a}n \cdot \frac{n-1}2 \cdot C\\
   &= (b-a) \cdot C \cdot \left(\frac 1{2n} + \frac{n-1}{2n} \right)\\
   &= (b-a) \cdot C \cdot \frac 12\\
   &= T(1).
\end{align*}
This proves (3), which implies (2).